# Should questions close on a user who is currently editing an answer

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, vote-to-close

It happened to me several times that a question closes while I am
answering. It may sometimes be more than an hour wasted. I would
expect not to be the only one to whom it happens.

Could there be a way such that someone who is working on an answer
gets warned of impending closure of the question, and get a delay of
an hour to complete somehow whatever he is writing, at least as a
temporary answer to be completed by editing.

One might think that the system is right in not encouraging posting
answers to questions that will be closed. I do not believe that since
deleting of a question (as opposed to closing) will depend on the
quality of the answers as well as that of the question.

For one thing, good answers to a bad question may be an incentive not
to vote deletion. Furthermore, the system itself discourages deleting
questions with upvoted answers, as "*[the number of delete votes
required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its
answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)*"

Hence, while on can undestand some motivations for closing a question,
there is no strong reason to waste work already done by a user. And
maybe let the community be the judge of it all. After all, that is
what voting is for.

This can be discussed at length, but the weirdest part is that the
system is rigged to give "*[a 4 hour window in which you can still
submit your answer, even though it is already closed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208206/closed-questions-pay-attention-to-those-who-are-answering/208208#208208)*". That is indeed more than I ask for.

But the the "post your question" button is disabled, without waiting
for the grace delay, so that it is not usable ... unless one knows how to hack the javascript, it is said.

Why this inconsistency?

Comment: Assuming that the closures votes you ran into are justified, the feature is good: it prevents you from wasting *even more* time. Also, the system is right in not encouraging posting answers to questions that will be closed. I think the basic message to take away for you is that you think questions are good that the community does not. You can (should?) try to "improve" your judgement so you don't waste time.

Comment: Moreover if there are down-votes/close-votes you might want to see if the question can be improved/clarified before answering.

Comment: @Kaveh The point is that the question is already mostly written, and I find
out it is closed when clicking the post button. Furthermore, given
that closing voters do not usually justify their vote (other than the
final closing comment, that is often far to imprecise to be much
help). I try to give answers that make sense given the question (I may
of course miss the mark), and that is often a better way to justify a
question than discussing why it should be answered.